# How to create a playlist after trimming down another based on rating?

Tags: windows-media-player, playlists, id3, music-management, smart-playlist

I want to create a mp3 playlist after trimming down another playlist (m3u). New playlist should contain only those mp3 whose "RATING WMP" ID3 tag value is 4 or 5 (this ID3 tag is used by WMP & Windows Library). How to do this?
WMP's *Auto Playlist* feature doesn't seem to work on a limited list other than full library.

Comment: I don't using WMP and haven't done so for years, but can't you sort by the Rating column in Explorer, select the top-rated songs and add them to a new playlist, perhaps by drag&drop?

Comment: @Karan Auto Ratings are messing up. Auto Ratings aren't saved in ID3 tag, but it appears in WMP Explorer & participates in sorting. Auto Playlist ignores Auto Ratings, but I am unable ignore Auto Ratings while doing mass select.

Answer (score 0):

The Auto Playlist feature indeed only works on a full library, but you can add additional criteria to narrow down the results. For example, you can give just the songs that you want to be returned a specific `Subgenre`, and check for that subgenre in the auto playlist. Or you could place these songs in their own folder and use the `File name Contains` criterium.

For more info about multi-criteria Auto Playlists, see

http://thewelltemperedcomputer.com/SW/WMP/Playlist.htm

Comment: Can you give me exact answer? I am unable to find any criteria to get to what I want. Placing mp3 files in one folder would not only screw my library but its also not practical.

Comment: Instead of using an M3U playlist, you give all the songs that you would normally put in the M3U playlist the same subgenre or place them in the same subfolder. These are just two examples to differentiate songs, and I don't see how the latter would screw up your library.

Comment: I want to use m3u because its compatible with mobile device sync...

Comment: You could try creating another auto playlist without any rating criteria (so that it would contain exactly the same songs as the M3U playlist). I'm not familiar with device syncing, but if you sync using WMP then I guess that it would automatically convert the auto playlist to an M3U playlist that the device understands.

Another option would be to simply load the M3U playlist in WMP, sort by rating, and manually add the highly-rated songs to another playlist.